# check each row in the mysql if there is changes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "inventory" and it has 4 column named "id, itemname, itembrand, datecreated" and it has 10 records (10 row). Now, what I'm trying to do is to check if any of those records has changes base from yesterdays records if no changes then throw no notifications else if it has changes then throw notification with which column and row has been changed. How to make it? any ideas, clues, recommendation, suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

what im looking is something like this code concept.

```
foreach(row as row) :
    // check each row if there is changes
    if (in this row has changes) {
        echo "column name of this row that has changes";
    }
endforeach;
```

I'm still searching on the internet for at least a little reference. Thank you.

Comment: Do you keep a history of the changes ? Show some sample data.

Comment: is there something like in mysql where it store a timestamp if within that record (row) column is changed? like mysqli_affected_row something like that which tells if the row is changed and it has date and time e.g. (changed 12:34 PM 03/26/2015) @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: assume that I have the yesterdays record saved, now, how to compare it with todays record so that I could check weither theres modification that has been done?

Comment: There is no way to keep track when something modified unless you keep track of history. Check here how history is kept, http://demo.sqcrm.com/  `U : admin   P: sqcrmdemo` , login and update a record, then go the detail view and check the history.

Comment: @CodeDemon You are right. but it will just return Number of rows affected by query. We cannot identify affected columns.

Answer (score 0):

Add one column to keep the record changes in DB like **'dateupdated'**,

each time while updating the field you update the **dateupdated** with current timestamp , this field will be used to find the changes done by yesterday or not .

Comment: thats cool but how about considering if there's no column like "dateupdated" and any ways to achieve that automatically? like mysql will tell you if that row as been modified?

Comment: This is like using flag variable for each row to find updates. But how will you find which column is updated. You can find updated row by using this, not the column.

Comment: Then only way to keep log table to store history of updated column with time

Comment: @Manadh: you got a point. sadly I have 88 tables inside a database and each tables contains thousands of records so it will be a big headache if i'll go through each records just to update there structure for this method (auto detect if theres changes in column or row) so as of now im looking a finest way to make everything automatic with less method implementation (automatic detection if theres a column or row modification base from yesterdays record to todays records)